# How to redirect user when a civicrm error message shows up?

Tags: error-page

Often I see in the drupal log that some people try to access invalid URLs. By default civi shows a message like this

> $Fatal Error Details = Array ( [message] => We can't load the
>   requested web page. This page requires cookies to be enabled in your
>   browser settings. Please check this setting and enable cookies (if
>   they are not enabled). Then try again. If this error persists, contact
>   the site administrator for assistance.
> Site Administrators:
>   This error may indicate that users are accessing this page using a
>   domain or URL other than the configured Base URL. EXAMPLE: Base URL is
>   http://example.org, but some users are accessing the page via
>   http://www.example.org or a domain alias like
>   http://myotherexample.org.
> Error type: Could not find a
>   valid session key. [code] => )

How can I redirect user to 404 page or similar page? Is it something possible to do? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be '[CiviCRM Report Error](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civicrm-error-report-handler)' extension may do your work! The extension does have setting to redirect from error page.